# PHPUnit stoping with no feedback when trying to dispatch in Zend Framework controllers

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

[EDIT] My test enviroment is as seen in http://www.slideshare.net/DragonBe/unit-testing-after-zf-18 and using the source from https://github.com/DragonBe/zfunittest.

When I try to run a simples dispatch("/"), I´m getting the following as answer:

```
C:\wamp\www\MyProject\tests>phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.19 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\MyProject\tests\phpunit.xml

.
C:\wamp\www\MyProject\tests>
```

Does anyone have a clue about what is happening?

The phpunit just stops and gives me no feedback.

I´m running Wampserver 2.2 over Windows 7x 64, ZF 1.11, PHP 5.4.3 and PHPunit 3.7.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you do a var_dump() after the dispatch() method call, do you see anything in the terminal?

Comment: You have misspelt `display_erros`, are you sure you are seeing errors?

Comment: display_errors is already correctly writen in my local copy. Nothing working yet. Actually, the issue comes only when I try to make dipsatchs. If I var_dump() before, the erros are displayed, but when I do $this->dispatch("/"), as an example, nothing else happens. The phpunit just print a "." and it finishs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve this problem, I tried to rewrite my files.

Removing ob_start() from the begining of my TestHelper.php, gave me the erros (thank God!), one after another, as I solved each of them (and phpunit was no more stoping execution):

- Session must be started before any output has been sent to the
  browser
- No default module defined for this application
- Fatal error: Call to a member function hasResource() on a non-object
  in ...ErrorController.php

After some search in other posts, I tried the following, in the setUp method of my IndexControllerTest.php:

```
public function setUp(){

    $this->bootstrap('session');
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setParam('noErrorHandler', true);
    $this->getFrontController()->setControllerDirectory(APPLICATION_PATH . '/controllers');
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Then, now this is working fine.

Thanks for all those who helped me.